# Why do the variables in my R boxplot not reflect my actual data?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am using `R` to analyse some ecological data, and when I try to create a boxplot two different boxes appear for one of my variables.

Here is my code:

```
plot(Ratio.gap.per ~ Circadian, data=circ)
```

which should produce a boxplot with a box for each of my x axis factors, but I always get two different bars for my category `N` (for 'nocturnal'). Boxplot shown here:

[image]

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure those two groups are identical? Rather than, say, `"N"` and `"N "`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of your data is coded as `"N "` (with a space) rather than `"N"`.

Try

`circ$Circadian[circ$Circadian=="N "] <- "N"`

and then if needed (i.e. if `circ$Circadian` is a factor),

`circ$Circadian <- as.factor(as.character(circ$Circadian))`

to get rid of the extra factor level.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's fixed it!